# Result of various Joins on a scenario

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables test1 and test2 both with single column containing some values.

I have applied the inner and outer joins but have confusion with the output.

```
Create table test1
( id int)
insert into test1 values (1)
insert into test1 values (1)
insert into test1 values (1)


Create table test2
( id int)
insert into test2 values (1)
insert into test2 values (1)
insert into test2 values (NULL)

select a.id from test1 a inner join test2 b on a.id = b.id
```

I was expecting,

```
1
1
Null
```

as output for inner join, left join and right join.

But the original output was,

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Could you please help me in understanding this on all the joins.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598900/3840840

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one of the three 1s in `test1` joined with each one of the two 1s in `test2`, and this yielded the 3x2=6 rows you got in the result-set. There is nothing different between the first,second and third 1 in `test1` and nothing different between the first and second 1 in `test2`.

Also, keep in mind that all of the following conditions:

```
NULL = 1
NULL <> 1
NULL = NULL
NULL <> NULL
```

are false. *All* conditions which have a NULL at one side will evaluate to false. This is because a NULL represents an unknown value.

What you expected is quite wrong, as you can see. It seems you expected the first row of `test1` to be joined with the first row of `test2` and so on. There is no such "magic" in sql - the entire logic of the join is placed within the `ON` clause, which joined the 1s as expained before.

Comment: You understood my doubt clearly. I was just thinking that only first row of test1 that has value 1 will join with only first row of test2 that has value 1.  But that's wrong. It will find all 1's in other table and join with it. Thanks.